Как вытащить информацию с amoCRM
пользуюсь библиотекой amocrm-js, мне нужно достать и вывести в свой html все созданные мной в ручную задачи, пользуюсь:
const { Client } = require('amocrm-js');
const config = require('./config');

const client = new Client(config);

(async () => {
    const status = await client.connection.connect();
    console.log({ status });
  
})();

Не могу понять как мне вытащить карточки задач из amoCRM кто нибудь поможет?

Наверное следует обратиться к данному эндпойнту, как это делать, описано в документации
